# How to avoid garbage collection when using Json?

Tags: libgdx

I'm currently loading my level with the `Json` classes. Problem is, the application lags at the beginning which is probably due to the GarbageCollector removing all my unused `JsonValue` objects. I don't currently know, how to fix this, any advice would be appreciated,

the WorldLoader class with the json stuff, code looks like much, but is pretty straight forward:

```
package com.Sidescroll.game.Helpers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.Sidescroll.game.GameObjects.Background;
import com.Sidescroll.game.GameObjects.Platform;
import com.Sidescroll.game.GameObjects.Player;
import com.Sidescroll.game.GameWorld.GameWorld;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonValue;

public final class WorldLoader {

    private WorldLoader() {}

    public static HashMap<String, GameWorld> worlds = new HashMap<String, GameWorld>();

    private static JsonValue jsonPlatforms, jsonSpawn, jsonBackgrounds;

    public static GameWorld loadWorld(String levelName) {
        if(worlds.get(levelName) != null) return worlds.get(levelName);

        //load json file
        FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("levels/" + levelName + ".json");
        String fileContent = handle.readString();
        JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(fileContent);

        jsonPlatforms = json.get("platforms");
        jsonBackgrounds = json.get("backgrounds");
        jsonSpawn = json.get("spawn");

        //loads platforms
        List<Platform> platforms = new ArrayList<Platform>();
        for(JsonValue pValue : jsonPlatforms.iterator()) {
            Platform platform = new Platform(pValue.getInt("x"),
                                    pValue.getInt("y"),
                                    pValue.getInt("width"),
                                    pValue.getInt("height"),
                                    Platform.Type.valueOf(Platform.Type.class, pValue.getString("type")),
                                    pValue.getString("variant"));
            platforms.add(platform);
        }

        //create player
        Vector2 vecSpawn = new Vector2(jsonSpawn.getInt("x"), jsonSpawn.getInt("y"));
        Player player = new Player(vecSpawn, platforms);

        //loads backgrounds
        List<Background> backgrounds = new ArrayList<Background>();
        for(JsonValue bgValue : jsonBackgrounds.iterator()) {
            Background bg = new Background("bin/sprites/" + bgValue.getString("name") + ".png",
                                            bgValue.getInt("x"),
                                            bgValue.getInt("y"),
                                            bgValue.getInt("width"),
                                            bgValue.getInt("height"),
                                            bgValue.getBoolean("front"));
            backgrounds.add(bg);
        }

        worlds.put(levelName, new GameWorld(player, platforms, backgrounds));
        return worlds.get(levelName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the issue? You have static references to your Json stuff, so it looks like they never go out of scope, so the GC will never claim them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But does the gc not get the `JsonValue` objects i create in the for loops?

Comment: Why don't you check this? You have DDMS in the Eclipse for example - you can check there how the GC is working and see if it's fireing is equal to the time point of the lag

Comment: one small trick i often do in my code is that i override finalize method in each of my class and do a print call in the class, this way whenever it is a garbage collection i can easily find which class it is which needs attention. Hope this helps you,

Comment: You're not creating JsonValues; you're only getting references to them. All the JsonValues from a single Json file are linked by a chain of references in the downstream direction. You are keeping references to some of the top level stuff. But if your Json file contains a lot of stuff outside of "platforms", "backgrounds", and "spawn" I suppose all those chains would get freed by the end of this method.

Comment: @m.antkowicz how do you use ddms in eclipse? ive been searchign but it seems you need android studio for that

Comment: @zebleckDAMM Window ->Open perspective -> DDMS

Comment: @m.antkowicz therse no DDMS shown when i go Window ->Open perspective -> DDMS and i cant seem to find a plugin for it, im using eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1), kinda strange. Also when I search for DDMS in eclipse, it doesnt find anything

Comment: @zebleckDAMM then you have to install ADT (if you have it installed maybe it is not "full" version?) look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Comment: @m.antkowicz whoops just found it when you linked me to it, will try DDMS out now ty

Comment: @m.antkowicz does DDMS work for desktop applications because Im not just using a desktop application and the emulator doesn't seem to see my desktop client when run

Comment: Im just using a desktop applicaton*

Comment: @zebleckDAMM I don't think so :( Emulator will see only android launcher instance - you need to have android project created